# What's the best method to be overloaded in ViewPage for inserting some script to all ViewPage?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert some script that is required for my JavaScript library in all view pages. I know that Asp.net MVC is built on Asp.net Framework. Therefore, I can override many methods in **“System.Web.UI.Page”** class that is a parent of **“System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage”** class.

Nevertheless, I can do it by override Render method but it makes all view pages be invalid for **XHTML 1.0 strict**. Correct JavaScript must be placed in header tag of HTML document.

```
public class ViewPage<TModel> : ViewPage where TModel : class 
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
        writer.Write("<script type='text/javascript>applicationPath = window.applicationPath = 'somePath';</script>");
    }
}
```

**Thanks,**

PS. I know I can create some code in each master page for doing that. However, it is a quite complicate for other developers to start using my JavaScript source code.

Comment: Personally I don't see how putting javascript in master page will confuse developers, even the most novice ones.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in code; do it in markup. Add the script tag to your Site.Master, in the correct, valid place.

Comment: It isn't impossible to do that. Developer who uses my source code at the first-time must learn a lot of things before write hello world page.

Comment: I didn't say that the other way was impossible. I said that putting it in markup was the *correct* way to do it, per MVC conventions. *Any* codebehind is arguably out of place in MVC views. So if you're worried about confusing other MVC developers, don't use it!

Answer (score 0):

I just see head of both View Page & View Master Page always run at server. Please look at the following templates.

**Default Template of ViewPage**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default Template of ViewMasterPage**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Therefore, it is very easy to solve this question by adding some control to header control.

```
public class ViewPage : mvc.ViewPage
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (Header == null)
            throw new Exception("Header object is null. Please set header runat=\"server\".");

        Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(CommonHelper.JavaScript(MvcUtils.GetApplicationUrl(Request) ,string.Empty)));

        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: However, I cannot use this answer in real-world application. Because most of ASP.net MVC application always have “<% %>” tag in header, so I cannot add new control to header control.